# How to execute queries stored in a string variable in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-ce

I have a table with the following schema, that contains TSQL queries.

| ID | ViewName | Query |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | vwPersons | Select * from tblPersons |
| 2 | vwPosts | Select * from tblPosts |

How can I select the second query (ID=2) from the above table and execute that query?

Comment: A table of views? Are you writing a new DBMS?

Comment: Nope, actually I use SQLCE, and all we know that SQLCE does not support features like View.

Comment: Removed answer, as it appears, sql server CE doesn't support dynamic querying. I don't think it's possible to do what you want in CE, unless you can do it in (.NET) application.